# How to find absolute path to @font-face fonts with Firebug?

Tags: css, firebug, font-face, google-chrome-devtools, absolute-path

Is there a way to copy (from Firebug for example) the absolute instead of the relative URL of a web font specified within an @font-face rule?

Example:

I'm viewing the main.css file for a site in Firebug and I get this:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "myfont";
    src: url("myfont__-webfont.eot");
}
```

How would I find the absolute path for this font?

I know that it should be next to the CSS file in this case, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: The Network or Resources tabs in F12 in Chrome could tell you... if the `.eot` actually loads (if not, the Console tab will tell you... if the CSS is actually applied).

Comment: What happens if enter: "http://<path to the css file>/myfont__-webfont.eot" in your browser's address bar? Firefox and all other browsers except IEs will not download '.eot' files, as they are only supported by IEs (see: http://caniuse.com/#feat=eot)

Comment: @Netsurfer I get a 404, for some reason.

Comment: @LeopoldKristjansson OK, so you know **the file does not exist** on the server (at least not in the referenced path). Due to the given URL in the CSS file it should be there (in this place). This should answer your question! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebug's [*CSS* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/CSS_Panel) currently doesn't offer an option to copy the URL of the webfont yet. So I created an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=7207), which was copied over to GitHub as [issue #7320](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/7320) asking for this feature.

Though there's another way to reach this:

1. Switch to the [*Net* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel) and enable it
2. Reload the page via **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>** (or **<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>** on Mac OS X, I guess; circumvents the fonts cache)
3. Click the *Fonts* filter
4. Right-click the request for the font and choose *Copy Location*

Comment: Did you reload the page via `Ctrl`+`F5` and not just with `F5`?

Comment: Yes I did... strange. Now I've actually solved my problems with a completely unrelated method. Thanks for helping though!

Comment: No problem. Would be great if you could post your solution as answer, so you can mark this question as resolved and others can get helped, too.

Comment: I would but the way I solved my problem (finding the font etc) has little to do with original question, but I'll add it to the thread in detail later this week. Maybe it could help some people.

Comment: @LeopoldKristjansson: Hey, if you found a way to get the font more quickly than through this Firebug method, could you give us a hint? P.S. Sebastian, great answer! This actually works, yay!

Comment: @Cerberus. I tend to use Chrome Dev Tools now to find the absolute path of font files if I have to - it's way easier. Still love firebug for many other things.

Comment: @LeopoldKristjansson: Ah, I see. I have tried that way, and it works. Thanks! But...is it really that much faster than through Firebug? They work about the same way?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1- Go myfont_*-webfont.eot
Step 2- Go Font-Face Generator service
Step 3- myfont*_-webfont.eot convert to web font.

Comment: What does your answer has to do with the question!? The question is exactly how to do what you describe in Step 1.

Comment: When you open "myfont_-webfont.eot" link, there will be an option to download it.

Comment: The question was, how to get the absolute path to the font. If I don't have that path I can not download it or do any of the above.